# file upload error codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, forms

I try to upload a file with code igniter but i get the error You did not select a file to upload.. Anyone knows how to resolve this? my var_dump shows this:

```
array(14) {
  ["file_name"]=> string(0) ""
  ["file_type"]=> string(0) ""
  ["file_path"]=> string(25) "./assets/profilepictures/"
  ["full_path"]=> string(25) "./assets/profilepictures/"
  ["raw_name"]=> string(0) ""
  ["orig_name"]=> string(0) ""
  ["client_name"]=> string(0) ""
  ["file_ext"]=> string(0) ""
  ["file_size"]=> NULL
  ["is_image"]=> bool(false)
  ["image_width"]=> NULL
  ["image_height"]=> NULL
  ["image_type"]=> string(0) ""
  ["image_size_str"]=> string(0) ""
}
```

my controller

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
   $id = $this->input->post('id_gids');

   $config['upload_path'] = './assets/profilepictures/';
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
   $config['max_size']    = '100000000';
   $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
   $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
   $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   $this->upload->do_upload('file');

   $image_path = $this->upload->data();
   $gidsimg = $image_path["file_name"];

   var_dump($image_path);
   var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());

   $data = array(
     'gids_name' => $this->input->post('voornaam'),
     'gids_surname' => $this->input->post('name'),
     'gids_city' => $this->input->post('stad'),
     'gids_email' => $this->input->post('mail'),
     'gids_password' => $this->input->post('password'),
     'gids_bio' => $this->input->post('bio'),
     'gids_year' => $this->input->post('jaar'),
     'gids_interest' => $this->input->post('studie'),
     'gids_picture' => "assets/profilepictures/".$gidsimg
   );

   $this->Mod_model->update($id, $data);
}
```

my view

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_gids" value="<?php echo $w['gids_id'] ?>"/>
  <div class="pictureprofile">
    <img src="../../<?php echo $w['gids_picture'] ?>" alt="Profile Picture" class="profilepicture">
  </div><br>
  <input type="file" name="gids_img"/><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using codeigniter and your form `action is empty`. don't know how your data reach to controller

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

change your form tag to `codignitor standers` and try

```
echo form_open_multipart('controller/function');
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
$this->upload->do_upload('file');
```

The parameter for the do_upload function is expecting the name of the file upload field, so you should change it to:

```
$this->upload->do_upload('gids_img');
```

Comment: Check the max_upload_size value in your php.ini file.  It might be that the image you are trying to upload is larger than the maximum allowed size